# Hide Title tag on image Hover

Tags: images, jquery

I would like to hide the image title tag when hovering an image as they aren't needed on my website.
I have tried this code below and added it above the closing `</head>` in header.php but it doesn't work.

I don't have to download a plugin to achieve this.
The title tag doesn't have an impact on SEO so there shouldn't be an issue with hiding it.

Would someone be able to tell me why my script isn't working and what I can do to make it work please?

This is the code I have tried in my header.php above the closing `</head>`

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('img').hover(function()
    { $(this).removeAttr('title'); });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Errors in console by pressing F12, Your code is correct but WordPress sometimes don't understands $, Use jQuery instead of $.

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    jQuery('img').hover(function() { 
        jQuery(this).removeAttr('title');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: This also doesn't seem to work and there's nothing in the console log either. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to run the above code from console, It will run or through error.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for jquery. Sole CSS can do that:

```
img[title],img:hover[title] {
opacity:0; /* both work, take what you prefer */
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
This removes the actual image itself on hover, not the title

Comment: This is my image html : 
<img title="number_step1" alt="Image of a number 1 bubble" data-src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/number_step1.png" class=" lazyloaded" src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/number_step1.png">

Answer (score 0):

Set the `pointer-events` CSS property to `none`.

```
img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```